# Trying To Create a Decently basic Hangman game. letters guessed aren't replacing the ones in the phrase

Tags: c++

Whenever I run the code, the output seems correct. However, trying to input a "guess" just loops what was previously outputted. I can't seem to figure out what's causing this to happen as in a sample code my colleague sent me, it ran perfectly.Additionally, I don't know where I would put the part of the code to decrease the amount of misses left, since whenever I try to add this, it would just lower this number for every letter that didn't match.(Keep in mind I am still relatively new to c++).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
void clearScreen();
void display(string s);

        ////Prints Underscores in place of Phrase
string getUnderscores(string s){
    string temp = "";
    for(int i=0; i < s.length(); i++){
        if(isalpha(s[i])){
            temp = temp + '_';
        }

        else
            temp += s[i];
    }
    return temp;
}
void display(string s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        cout << s[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main () {
    string phrase;
    int chances = 7;
    ////Randomized Category and Phrase Within That Category
    srand(time(0));
    char categories[4][20] = {"Movie Title", "Around the House", "Phrase", "Place"};
    string Movie_Title_phrases[20] =            {"Fantastic Beasts And Where To Find Them", "Rogue One: A Star Wars Story",
                                                 "The Perks Of Being A Wallflower", "Batman V Superman: Dawn Of Justice",
                                                 "The Last Days On Mars", "Night Of The Living Dead", "Man Of A Thousand Faces",
                                                 "The Secret Life Of Pets", "Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban",
                                                 "The Lost World: Jurassic Park", "Snow White & The Seven Dwarves",
                                                 "Captain America: The First Avenger", "Rise Of The Planet Of The Apes",
                                                 "Tinker Bell And The Lost Treasure", "The Man Who Shot Liberty Valance",
                                                 "The Bone Bridge: A Brother's Story", "Indiana Jones And The Last Crusade",
                                                 "Cloudy with a Chance of Meatballs", "Mr. Smith Goes to Washington",
                                                 "Avengers: Endgame"};
    string Around_The_House_phrases[20] =       {"A Vase Of Fresh Cut Garden Flowers", "A Pile Of Coats On The Bed",
                                                 "Alarm Clock With Nature Sounds", "Fluffy Pillows And Soft Blankets",
                                                 "Scented Candles In Mason Jars", "Set Of Six Shot Glasses",
                                                 "Angle Broom With Dustpan", "Art Deco Bedroom Set",
                                                 "Bathroom Cleaner With Bleach", "Comfortable Couch & Love Seat",
                                                 "Black-And White Family Photograph",
                                                 "Door Swinging Wide Open", "Handblown Crystal Wine Glasses",
                                                 "Four-Piece Patio Furniture Set", "Matching Bathmats & Shower Curtains",
                                                 "Patterned Fabric Shower Curtain", "Portable Wireless Outdoor Speaker",
                                                 "Scented Hand Soap & Moisturizer", "Stackable Plastic Storage Containers",
                                                 "Automatic Garage-Door Opener"};
    string Phrase_phrases[20] =                 {"Fifty-Percent-Off Sale", "Astronomically Small",
                                                 "A Little Bit Of This And A Little Bit Of That",
                                                 "You Took The Words Right Out Of My Mouth",
                                                 "You Can't Have Too Much Of A Good Thing",
                                                 "If At First You Don't Succeed Try Try Again",
                                                 "If You've Got Something To Say Then Say It",
                                                 "I Think We Got Off On The Wrong Foot", "Someday We'll Have A Good Laugh About This",
                                                 "Which Came First The Chicken Or The Egg?", "This Has Been A Real Treat For Me",
                                                 "Don't Let The Cat Out Of The Bag", "It's The Most Wonderful Time Of The Year",
                                                 "The Apple Doesn't Fall Far From The Tree", "All Good Things Come To Those Who Wait",
                                                 "You Can't Judge A Book By Its Cover", "You Have To See It To Believe It",
                                                 "I Wouldn't Want To Be In Your Shoes", "I Forgot What I Was Trying To Say",
                                                 "I Wouldn't Do That If I Were You"};
    string Place_phrases[20] =                  {"A Caribbean Hot Spot", "Adventureland", "Campground",
                                                 "Hogwarts School Of Witchcraft And Wizardry", "State Of The Art Fitness Center",
                                                 "The Deep End Of The Pool", "The Shores Of The Great Lakes",
                                                 "A Villa On A Private Island", "Cafe In A Quiet Courtyard", "Campsite Deep In A Canyon",
                                                 "Private Museum Of Russian Art", "Rooftop Bar With Heated Pool",
                                                 "Sensational Islands Of The World", "Tallest Building In The World",
                                                 "The Lost And Found Department", "The Lost City Of Atlantis", "The Valleys Of The Alps",
                                                 "A Great Vacation Destination", "Children's Interactive Science Museum",
                                                 "End Of The Trail"};
    int random = rand() % 4;
    string category = categories[random];
    int randphrase = rand() % 20;
    if (random == 0) {
        phrase = Movie_Title_phrases[randphrase];
    }
    if (random == 1) {
        phrase = Around_The_House_phrases[randphrase];
    }
    if (random == 2) {
        phrase = Phrase_phrases[randphrase];
    }
    if (random == 3) {
        phrase = Place_phrases[randphrase];
    }
    ////Copy of Phrase to convert to underscores.
    string phrase2 = phrase;
    clearScreen();

    cout << "Category: " << category << endl;
    cout << "Phrase: ";


    //// Converts Phrase To Uppercase Letters
    for (int i = 0; i < phrase2.size(); i++) phrase2[i] = toupper(phrase2[i]);
    phrase = phrase2;
    string phraseUND = getUnderscores(phrase);

    ////Guessing
    char guess;
    do {
        display(phraseUND);
        cout << "Enter a letter: \n";
        cin >> guess;
        for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
            if (phrase[i] == guess) {
               phraseUND[i] = phrase[i];
            }
        }
        cout << "______________________________________________________________" << endl;
        cout << "Game Over After " << chances << " incorrect guesses!" << endl;
        cout << "Category: " << category << endl<< "Phrase: ";
    } while (phraseUND != phrase);
}   
void clearScreen() {
    system("CLS");
}
```

Comment: You should convert `guess` to upper case since you set the `phrase` to all upper case.

Comment: Any ideas on how to lower the chances counter? It lowers by a substantial amount since it lowers for each letter checked.

Comment: add a boolean variable initialized to false at begiing of guessing. if letter was guessed you set it to true. If it still false after look-up done, you 'll decrease the counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your main issue is you are not converting the user input to upper case. Since you also want to update the score with each guess, I would create a function that checks for a match, replaces the underscores, and returns 1 if no match or 0 if a match. This seems backwards, since 0 usually means failure, but you can use this value to update the score:

```
int checkLetter(string& source, string& underscores, char c)
{
    if (!isalpha(c)) return 0;
    c = toupper(c);

    int return_value = 1;
    for (auto i = 0; i < source.length(); i++) {
        if (c == source[i]) {
            underscores[i] = c;
            return_value = 0;
        }
    }
    return return_value;
}
```

And your main loop becomes:

```
    do {
        display(phraseUND);
        cout << "Enter a letter: \n";
        cin >> guess;
        chances -= checkLetter(phrase, phraseUND, guess);
        cout << "______________________________________________________________" << endl;
        cout << "Game Over After " << chances << " incorrect guesses!" << endl;
        cout << "Category: " << category << endl << "Phrase: ";
    } while (phraseUND != phrase && chances > 0);
```

Note, I also changed the while condition to quit after all guesses are used up.